# Blank screen with *working* cursor & input on startup

Tags: pi-4, gui

Background:
I’ve got an RPi4 running TwisterOS. I installed Lutris and a game on it.
The game worked fine, but was running in windowed mode, and I couldn’t get it to run in fullscreen. I went into the settings and enabled SDL 1.2 fullscreen, and then launched the game.
The screen was black, but there was sound from the game, and keyboard input worked.

Issue:
I shutdown my pi with the on/off switch provided in the canakit starter kit I bought.
When I restarted my pi, it booted to a blank screen, with a working cursor.
I added autostart files to play an mp3 with mpg123 and open a bash terminal on startup, and the music still played, and I was able to type in “pkill mpg123” to stop it, all with a blank screen.
When I move my mouse to the top of the screen, it shows the text for icons as though I’m hovering over them, and when I click on the top left, the start menu dropdown shows up.

I’m able to access the terminal by hitting ctrl-alt-f2, and the screen works fine there, except the terminal doesn’t entirely fit on the screen.
I’m also able to launch a game using a memorized command from the blank screen, and it’s rendered properly, so just the GUI isn’t working.

Could it be something wrong with the resolution from launching the game with a wrong setting for the display?

Any suggestions what to try?

Thanks.

Comment: Same symptoms here after logging in via `root` `linux` to `openSUSE-Tumbleweed-ARM-GNOME-raspberrypi.aarch64-2021.09.21-Snapshot20211008.raw.xz`. I was able to do your `ctrl+alt+f2` trick to login as `root` `linux` again, and then enter `shutdown`.

Comment: `openSUSE-Tumbleweed-ARM-XFCE-raspberrypi.aarch64-2021.09.21-Snapshot20211008.raw.xz` worked fine, flashed via Raspberry Pi Imager. However, on a restart, it hung after login, with wallpaper and cursor and nothing else.

Comment: `openSUSE-Tumbleweed-ARM-KDE-raspberrypi.aarch64-2021.09.21-Snapshot20211008.raw.xz` same symptoms, flashed via Balena Etcher and Raspberry Pi Imager.